# Load TTF font instead of OTF

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts

I have two fonts with the same name, but different extensions (ttf and otf). If I do

```
Font f = Resources.Load("Fonts/bimasakti") as Font;
```

the variable `f` gets an instance of the otf font, which is quite reasonable as I'm guessing the loader is searching for files in alphabetical order. Anyways, if I do

```
Font f = Resources.Load("Fonts/bimasakti.ttf") as Font;
```

the variable `f` gets `null`ed, which means that the loader can't find the ttf font.

Why is that and how can I force the loader to load my ttf font instead of the otf?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible, at least for now. The only way I could think of is renaming the files to bimasaktiTTF.ttf & bimasaktiOTF.otf. Or if you don't want to rename you could put them in two separated folders (OTF/bimasakti.otf & TTF/bimasakti.ttf).

As the docs stated: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

> ... extensions must be omitted.

Take a look here as well:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/595837/prefab-with-same-name-and-path-as-model.html

and here

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/64110/how-to-identifyget-the-file-name-of-resources-load.html